# ggplot2::geom_smooth(): What contributes to the "smoothness" of lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Take a look at those two plots:

1. ["Not so smooth" lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r73yj.png)  (source: RStudio running on my machine)
2. ["Smooth" lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H5AJ.png) (source: [ggplot homepage](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html))

Apparently, the same data and code is used to produce these two plots. But the second plot looks a lot nicer because the lines are much "smoother". On my machine (Windows 10, screen resolution 1920x1080) the lines always look pretty "pixilated", as you see in the first plot (regardless of which image resolution I choose). I want to know what makes the difference here!

Thank you!

Code used to produce the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(span = 0.8) +
  facet_wrap(~drv)
```

Comment: I think anti aliasing is the culprit. Try exporting to a vector format and checking then.

Comment: Oh, it was just as simple as that! I already was thinking about that solution but I only looked at the preview of the vector format (which didn't look any different), haha. Thank you very much!